# Div with 70% opacity containing images with 100% opacity

Tags: css, opacity

I have a `div` element with `opacity: 0.7;`. I set that because I want all the text inside it to be opaque. Inside this `div` I want also to show some images, but I would like to have opacity 100% on these images, and not 0.7. I tried by setting `opacity: 1;` to the images but they are shown opaque no matter what.

How can I solve this problem? I've searched around but couldn't find any solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The child of an element with transparency (`opacity` < 1), cannot be less transparent than its parent. So `opacity: 1` will have the effect only making the child element equally transparent as its parent, but no more so.

To have partially transparent text you could, instead, use:

```
div {
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/7twXW/).

Which I think is supported by the same browsers that support the `opacity` property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rgba(0,0,0,0.7);` color values for the background and text color in CSS:

```
div
{
    background: rgba(100,12,100,0.7);
    color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
}​
```

You can convert #hex color codes to rgb [here](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/hextorgb.htm).

http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/FQKXv/

---

FOR IE

You can use their `filter` code:

```
div 
{ 
       background:transparent;
       filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#55992200,endColorstr=#55992200); 
       zoom: 1;
}
```

The hex value has 8 digits instead of 6. The last two are the alpha value. Adjust to taste.

Comment: ie6, ie7 and ie8 doesn't support `rgba`. It works starting from ie9.

Answer (score 1):

Use RGBA code for that, its a css3 property and old browser like ie7, ie8 does not support it

```
R= red
G= green
B= blue
A= alpha

div {
   background: rgba(200, 54, 54, 0.5); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am mentioning the property through in which you can increase and decrease the opacity of parent container background and that will not affect the child container. It's simple see the css basically you have to use the rgb color in background & alpha for opacity.

**CSS**     `background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);`

or see the demo :- http://jsfiddle.net/8LFLd/102/

Answer (score 0):

As said a hundreds of times through dozens of questions:

```
.transparent {
    /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7*/
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#70000000, endColorstr=#99000000);
    /* For IE 8*/
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#70000000, endColorstr=#99000000)";
}
```

This is the cross-browser solution.